# Js slideToggle not triggering on-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Stepping in because I'm a running into some problems with this function. I've got the same working for my nav (fadeToggle), but this is proving elusive. What I want is to hit the h2 element, and have it slide the parent div to the class 'reveal'.

Any ideas?

Script:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(“div.sub-hold h2").click(function(){
       $(this).parent().find($("div.reveal","div.sub-hold”)).slideToggle(500);
    });
  });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="sub-content , col-xs-2-2 , col-sm-3 , col-md-3 , col-lg-7">
    <h1><?php echo $main; ?></h1>
    <div class="sub-hold">
                <h2><?php echo $item; ?></h2>
                <h3><?php echo $sub; ?></h3> 
    </div>               
    <div class="reveal"><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>"/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is just in your example above or your real code but it looks like you have a couple of curly Word style quotes. For example, the first one in `$(“div.sub-hold h2")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit correction in your code.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $("div.sub-hold h2").click(function(){
           $(this).closest('.sub-content').find("div.reveal,div.sub-hold").slideToggle(500);
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick:

```
$("div.sub-hold h2").click(function(){
   $(this).parent().find(".reveal").slideToggle(500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how slideToggle works:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.sub-hold h2").click(function(){
       $("div.reveal, div.sub-hold").slideToggle(500);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sub-content , col-xs-2-2 , col-sm-3 , col-md-3 , col-lg-7">
    <h1><?php echo $main; ?></h1>
    <div class="sub-hold">
                <h2>h2</h2>
                <h3>h3</h3> 
    </div>               
    <div class="reveal"><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>"/></div>
</div>
```

Would like to know what you want to achieve, as its bit unclear from your description and code.

Comment: Strike Comment - DJ Yadav provided answer

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple instances"? Would be great, if you can share HTML or some stuff to understand the issue.